# Is it possible to use a combiner function when flatMap in Java?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have this code:

```
userRepo.findAll().stream()
    .map(u -> {
        u.setName(name);
        return u;
    })
    .flatMap(u -> {
        return employeeRepo.findById(u.getId());
    }, //???)
```

In `//???`, I need a combiner function to get both User and Employee. I know how to do it in RxJava but not in plain Java. Is that possible?

Comment: You'd need to return some sort of `Pair` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like:

```
Map<User, Employee> userEmployee = userRepo.findAll().stream()
    .map(u -> {
        u.setName(name);
        return u;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
      u -> u,
      u -> employeeRepo.findById(u.getId())
    ))
```

This will create a map with `User` as key and `Employee` as value.

Answer (score 1):

The most functional way would be to use what scala desugars for comprehensions to: Nested `flatMap`s and one `map` in the deepest nesting.

```
userRepo.findAll().stream()
    .flatMap(u -> {
        u.setName(name); //I don't like this line
        return employeeRepo.findById(u.getId()).map(e->{
            return new Pair(u,e);
        });
    });
```

Assuming there's a class `Pair`.